# In YAML how to use value from another key

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file like below.

```
Details:
    Name: Jack
    Location: USA
    ABC: TestValue
Refer:
    Test1: %Details.Name%
    Test2: %Details.Location%
```

Wanted to check if the value given in Test1 works? As I know if **%Details.Name%** is present under parameters. But above keys are not parameters. So, is there any way to refer the values from another key?

Answer (score 3):

There are anchors and aliases, which you can use like this:

```yaml
Details:
    Name: &name Jack
    Location: &location USA
    ABC: TestValue
Refer:
    Test1: *name
    Test2: *location
```

However, there is no way to refer to other values via their „paths“. Applications using YAML may support pre- or postprocessing to do this (often via templating engines like Jinja), but plain YAML doesn't implement this feature.

If you are under the impression that `%Details.Name%` would work in some context, you are already using a pre- or postprocessing feature that is not plain YAML.