# In YAML use key value from another key and append string

Tags: yaml

I have a yaml file like the below.

```
Field1:
  Key1: A1
  Key2: A2
```

I would like to use the key values of keys in `Field1` to populate key values of another key (say `Field2`) in the same yaml file. During the creation of key values in `Field2`, I would like to use key values of keys in `Field1` and append them to another string (say "test").

Below is an example of what I want in the yaml file:

```
Field1:
  Key1: A1
  Key2: A2

Field2:
  NewKey1: A1_test
  NewKey2: A2_test
  NewKey3: A1_A2
```

**How can I achieve the above?**

I saw from this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74961544/in-yaml-how-to-use-value-from-another-key) that one can use anchors and aliases. But, they look like they can help in only copying the value of a given key. I want to append a string or different key values to a key value in addition to copying.

Comment: You tagged [tag:pyyaml], do you want to do this in Python? YAML in general is not a programming language and can't do data transformations.

Comment: flyx: I use `import yaml` or `hydra` mostly for reading yaml files.